# Seagate hard drive not detected by ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, boot-repair, boot-partition

My 500 GB seagate hard drive not detected by [ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386].

History:

Earlier I was getting blue screen 4/5 times. I used to restart the computer and do my work as usual. But last week when blue screen came I restart the computer but it did not start, its shows `verifying pool data insert system disk`.

Later I made a boot-able disk with [ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386] and try to access my hard drive but it could not detect it.

I am having 500 GB seagate hard drive with 4 partition, C, D, E, F.

Can you please help me to access my hard drive and my files.

***500 GB HARD DISK SHOWING ONLY 4GB CAPACITY AND NOT BOOTING***

The output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda     8:0    0   3.9G  0 disk 
sdb     8:16   1   7.3G  0 disk /media/ubuntu/6CEA-B40B
sr0    11:0    1  1015M  0 rom  /cdrom
loop0   7:0    0 978.3M  1 loop /rofs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Thank you,

Milan Hazra

the output

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sdb: UUID="6CEA-B40B" TYPE="vfat" 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sdb: UUID="6CEA-B40B" TYPE="vfat" 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# /etc/fstab
bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sdb: UUID="6CEA-B40B" TYPE="vfat" 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# gedit/etc/fstab
bash: gedit/etc/fstab: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# gedit

(gedit:5095): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:5095): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# -a
-a: command not found
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount -a
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

`/srv` folder has 0 files to check

Thanks

Milan

Comment: Sounds like you need to warranty it out if available

Comment: how do you know it is not detected by ubuntu? please run the command lsblk in a terminal and please post the output in your question, thanks

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu please explain how to run the command Isblk in a terminal

Comment: ANYBODY PLEASE HELP!

Comment: execute this command `blkid` at command prompt (sudo su yourself into root before executing the command).  Does it list your hard drive?

Comment: @mchidPlease find the output of the command lsblk....

Comment: Sir, how to do sudo su yourself into root.. I didn't understand.

Comment: type `sudo su` and enter your password to it.  You will then move to 'root' level.  You need root level before you could be able to configure or repair anything on the system.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But what password should I use as I was not having any password earlier with this computer.

Comment: normally its the same password that you use to access your system

Comment: If you can't access to your root level from your normal username, then I am afriad there isn't much you can do without root.  You really need the root before all of this to work.

Answer (score 1):

With little information from your case, but, off the top of my head, this is what I would do if I were in your position.

I'd `sudo su` myself into root, then execute `blkid`.  It will list all drives that are supposed to be mounted with the system.  Here's an example from my system that blkid would list:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="eec0e15e-4c30-409e-815b-58ff37ba97e2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="47e0e641-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="c02becce-6f63-428a-b88d-c7761af1d9b6" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="47e0e641-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="8a459b28-ac81-419e-b25f-7ac49d48a297" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="03e8b2e8-01"
```

All of items that is being listed by `blkid` are typically what should be already on /etc/fstab.  By default, it is not surprise if it only lists your first hard drive (which is always /dev/sda).

You would notice /dev/sdb1 line from `blkid`, and that is actually 2nd hard drive. By root level, you open /etc/fstab and edit the file by adding this line (copied from `blkid`). [To make things easier for you - when you are still in root level, do `gedit /etc/fstab`.  It'll pop up a editor on your screen and in that document, you edit it and save and close the appication and go back to terminal]

```
dev/sdb1: UUID="8a459b28-ac81-419e-b25f-7ac49d48a297" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="03e8b2e8-01"
```

and that line to this format:

```
UUID="8a459b28-ac81-419e-b25f-7ac49d48a297" /srv  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0 1
```

Save the file; then execute `mount -a`.

Once that's done, you can navigate in your file system by going to /srv folder, and you should see your stuff in that folder.